# CMake cannot find MathGL's dependency PNG

Tags: cmake, mathgl

I'm trying to generate Visual Studio 2013 projects files for MathGL 2.3.3 with CMake.

For some reason cmake does not understand my PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR statement.

```
cmake "-DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=c:\users\chenning\projects\zlib-1.2.8\" "-DZLIB_LIBRARY_DEBUG=c:\users\chenning\projects\zlib-1.2.8\zlib.lib" "-DZLIB_LIBRARY_Release=c:\users\chenning\projects\zlib-1.2.8\zlib.lib" "-DPNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\Users\chenning\projects\lpng1620\" "-DPNG_LIBRARY_DEBUG=C:\Users\chenning\projects\lpng1620\projects\vstudio\x64\Debug\libpng16.lib" "-DPNG_LIBRARY_Release=C:\Users\chenning\projects\lpng1620\projects\vstudio\x64\Release\libpng16.lib" .
```

The Path exists and the variable is really called PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR  with two PNG.

cmake is telling me:

```
-- Found ZLIB: c:\users\chenning\projects\zlib-1.2.8\zlib.lib
-- Could NOT find PNG (missing:  PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:341 (message):
  Couldn't find PNG library.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/chenning/projects/mathgl-2.3.3/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/chenning/projects/mathgl-2.3.3/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

When I set the paths with cmake-gui all works fine.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Have you cleared the CMake chache?

Comment: Yes, I did remove the CMakeFiles folder but the error remains.

Comment: Having a look into the most recent MathGL code, it looks like you should set `PNG_INCLUDE_DIR`. Why do you assume you have to use the `PNG_PNG_` prefix?

Comment: Look at the output of cmake in my question. It does ask for PNG_PNG_...

Comment: Your right, that's an oddity of CMake's FindPNG.cmake. What's the complete path to png.h?

Comment: C:\Users\chenning\projects\lpng1620

Comment: Have you tried adding `png.h` to `PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR`?